# Deployed website doesn't display in Internet explorer

Tags: node.js, angular, internet-explorer, iis, iisnode

I have deployed an app into IIS. It is node.js and angular app,deployed using iisnode. The deployed works as expected inside google chrome but not inside Internet explorer.

When I inspect using debug element I found the following issues. Do I need run angular PROd, specific to Internet explorer?

Here is the screenshot of the errors I get inside Internet explorer.

**My current version of angular-cli is 7.3.9**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

By default, Angular is not supporting IE. In order to enable the support, you need to modify src\polyfills.ts file.
In this file look for /** IE9, IE10 and IE11 require all of the following polyfills. **/ and uncomment all the imports.
In addition to that, you need to enable import classlist.js 
If classlist.js is not present then execute the command

```
npm install --save classlist.js
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify the `polyfill.ts` to make Angular app supported in IE. Please open the `polyfill.ts` file and read the annotation, uncomment the import lines needed in IE. Then install some packages with npm:

```
npm install --save classlist.js
npm install --save web-animations-js
```

For further information, you could refer to [this article](https://blog.angularindepth.com/angular-and-internet-explorer-5e59bb6fb4e9).

If you have uncommented imports and it still doesn't work, you could try to add meta tag in the index.html: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />`.